# RxJs implementing refresh action from Observable chain

Tags: angular, rxjs

trying to implement refresh or poll with rxjs chain.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const id$ = this.route.params;

    id$.subscribe((params: Params) =>  {
        this.id = params['id'];
        this.userService.getUser(params['id']).subscribe(this.getUserSubject$));
    }

    this.getUserSubject$
      .flatMap(user =>
        Observable.forkJoin(this.userService.getAddress(user), this.userService.isActive(user),
          (address, isActive) => {
            return _.assign({}, user, address, {isActive: isActive});
          }
        )
      )
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user
      }, err => this.error(err));
}

refresh($event) {
    this.userService.getUser(this.id).subscribe(this.getUserSubject$);
}
```

On refresh call the getUserSubject$ chain is not called. 
its called just once on ngOnInit.
how to push data into the getUserSubject$, so that user is updated.
why the observable chain in not called from refresh.

Comment: the subscribe call needs at least one function as argument..??

Comment: Apologies, just checked docs, you can pass an observer too! Sorry, will delete

Comment: @danimal Please don't delete your comments especially if someone has replied to it - it dilutes future reference.

Comment: Since `this.getUserSubject$` looks like an instance of `Subject` I think you're affected by this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/9518/subject/29424/subject-and-its-internal-state#t=201704281244358254133 If not, post reproducible example.

Comment: @martin: thanks, yeah subject was  in completed state. is there any other way in which i could have restructured the above code in more elegant way.

Comment: @vito You can pass only the `next` signals to the Subject with `.subscribe(val => this.getUserSubject$.next(val))`.